# how to check mat-dialog change detection and remove detection in angular 5

Tags: angular-material, angular5

I am new to angular. I need to know to check mat-dialog change detection and if possible I need to remove detection. How can I check it.

Comment: What do you mean by change detection?

Comment: When I did profiling for a mat-dialog it did lot of angular change detection. So I want to know about it

Comment: *it did lot of angular change detection* --> For example?

Comment: I am looking for answer to my question. Please let me know if you know about it. If we do profiling in chrome for mat-dialog, you will know about the change detection.

Comment: Yes exactly need explanation otherwise let it be!

Comment: You can set the `changeDetection` property in the `Component` decorator: https://angular.io/api/core/Component#changeDetection